# Counting created comments for all Posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

There's 1 comment for Post #2. When I try to create the **first** comment for Post #1, I get

> /posts/1/comments/2

On comment's index page, it lists the same comments for all Posts, regardless of their ID.

---

comments_controller

```
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html { redirect_to [@post, @comment], notice: 'It was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'index', status: :created, location: @comment }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

routes

```
resources :posts do
    resources :comments
end
```

Comment: Please share `index` action for CommentsController. Also, share the routes for posts and comments.

Comment: Where do you set `@post` for index action. Also, share the contents of `routes.rb`.

Comment: Let's discuss this on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On comment's index page, it lists the same comments for all Posts,
>   regardless of their ID.

You must have defined `CommentsController#index` as below:
    def index
      @comments = Comment.all
    end
which is why on comment's index page, you see same comments for all posts.

Assuming that you have nested routes as:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

Update `CommentsController#index` as below:

```
def index
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comments = @post.comments
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should drop the database and recreate it again in order to start counting from the beginning.

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
```

It is all about auto increment feature for keys (like :id) in databases.